# Why can't I define a new type in ghci?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I get an error in ghci when I try to define a new type:

```
Prelude> data Point = Pt Int Int
<interactive>:1:0: parse error on input `data'
Prelude> let data Point = Pt Int Int
<interactive>:1:4: parse error on input `data'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to define new ADTs in GHCi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849716/is-it-possible-to-define-new-adts-in-ghci)

Comment: @newacct: I asked this question before the question you linked to was asked.

Comment: As Alexey Romanov says below you can in ghc 7.4.1 and up.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`titaniumdecoy`, I remember being helped with this sort of GHCi mystery when I learned the frequently made point that writing things like 'let square x = x * x' inside the GHCi is like writing `let a = f b` with `do` notation in the `IO` monad -- say in this sort of example:

```
palindromize :: IO ()
palindromize = do
  a <- readFile "foo.txt"
  let b = reverse a
  putStrLn (a ++ b)
```

Similarly, when you redefine an expression in the GHCi, it's sort of like doing the following in `do` notation, which is perfectly legitimate:

```
makeMess :: IO ()
makeMess = do
   a <- readFile "foo.txt"
   let b = reverse a
   putStrLn (a ++ b)
   let b = a
   putStrLn (a ++ b)
```

No one would *declare a data type* in the middle of such a sequence, but would do it elsewhere in the module.  I might have guessed that there was some sort of theoretical objection, but Don S.'s remark suggests there isn't one.

Answer (score 23):

It is [possible since GHC 7.4.1](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.4.1/docs/html/users_guide/release-7-4-1.html#id3016169).

Answer (score 13):

ghci does not allow you to define types from interactive input - instead, you need to put your type definition in a file and `:load` the file into ghci.

Answer (score 13):

Just for historical reference, the [HBI Haskell interactive environment](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Implementations#HBI_and_HBC.2C_Chalmers.27_Haskell_Interpreter_and_Compiler) allows for full Haskell at the command line, including types, classes and so on. There's no *a priori* GHCi can't operate similarly, and users could write a front-end to GHC-API that supported this...