# Data.list error not picking up command?

Tags: haskell

[image: error image]

The code I am using keeps popping up with this error of not being able to find "change", how can I fix this problem? Is there something I need to download for it to work? Also, if needed, do I need to fix any other component of this for it to run smoothly?  I'm new to Haskell!

Comment: Enter your code into a .hs file and load it into GHCi.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell error parse error on input \`='](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184940/haskell-error-parse-error-on-input)

Comment: please don't include pictures of code but text instead which can be read better and copy&pasted...

Comment: You can't just paste the contents of a Haskell source file into WinGHCI and hope it will work. You'll need to put that code into a file and then load the file with GHCi using commands like :load and :reload . It's possible to define multi-line things in GHCi but the syntax is not the same as a file.